# Local Image Path in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and am facing an issue, I am not able to reference the images that I have in.
In my code directory I have src folder in which I have components and images directories.
In components I have a component called Header.js where I am trying to access an image from the src/images directory but its not getting displayed.
I have lots of images to display and I am not sure how do I achieve this.

```
<div className="brand">
                        <img
                            className="logo"
                            src= "shopping-cart/src/images/Veggy.png"                           
                            alt="Veggy Brand Logo"
                        />
</div>
```

I have tried removing src or adding ../ but doesn't seems to work.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you try 
 
       <img
          className="logo"
          src= {require('/images/Veggy.png')}                         
          alt="Veggy Brand Logo"
        />   Or importing your image first usng import * as Image "images/Veggy.png" and using it later

Answer (score 0):

Use import to import the image

```
  import veggy from "shopping-cart/src/images/Veggy.png";
```

And then pass veggy to src

```
   <div className="brand">
                    <img
                        className="logo"
                        src={veggy}                         
                        alt="Veggy Brand Logo"
                    />
   </div>
```

Or use require directly

```
    src = require("shopping-cart/src/images/Veggy.png")
```